# Why my menu closes immediately after opening on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

My menu closes immediately after opening on mobile devices. In console I can see the following error

> jquery.js:3 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Can someone please help me out? Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="property-details.html">Property details</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="responsive-menu-button">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click touchstart', '.responsive-menu-button', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var contentSize = parseInt( $( 'header.header-bar .header-bar-top .container' ).css( 'width' ), 10 );
    var responsiveMenuWidth = contentSize < 750 ? ( contentSize <= 370 ? 180 : 250 ) : 300;

    if( martanianLuxuryApartmentsResponsiveMenuVisible == false ) {
        var wrapper = $( '.big-wrapper' );
        var wrapperWidth = wrapper.width();
        var headerBar = $( this ).parents( 'header.header-bar' );

        headerBar.animate({ 'left': '-'+ responsiveMenuWidth +'px' }, 300 );
        wrapper.animate({ 'margin-left': '-'+ responsiveMenuWidth +'px', 'width': wrapperWidth }, 300 );

        $( '.responsive-menu-content' ).css({ 'display': 'block' }).animate({ 'right': '0' }, 300 );
        martanianLuxuryApartmentsResponsiveMenuVisible = true;
    }
    else {
        var wrapper = $( '.big-wrapper' );
        var wrapperWidth = wrapper.width();
        var headerBar = $( this ).parents( 'header.header-bar' );

        headerBar.animate({ 'left': '0' }, 300 );
        wrapper.animate({ 'margin-left': '0' }, 300 );

        $( '.responsive-menu-content' ).css({ 'display': 'block' }).animate({ 'right': '-'+ responsiveMenuWidth +'px' }, 300 );

        setTimeout( function() {

            $( '.responsive-menu-content' ).css({ 'display': 'none' });
            wrapper.css({ 'margin-left': '', 'width': '' });
            headerBar.css({ 'left': '' });

        }, 300 );
        martanianLuxuryApartmentsResponsiveMenuVisible = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share HTML?

Comment: I've added my HTML

Comment: html not enough to solve your question, provide pen or fiddle of your problem

Comment: Here is the website: http://marbella-luxvilla.ml/. If you have a look at it on your mobile, you'll see how the menu closes immediately after opening.